# APPLICATION FAILED TO START: Erro de persistencia ao iniciar a aplicação

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

**Projeto Completo:** https://github.com/codenome/ponto-inteligente-api

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Spring Boot, e ao iniciar a aplicação acabei encontrando um erro que não consegui resolver depois de horas de pesquisas.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-11-05 13:19:58.351 ERROR 17220 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method javax.persistence.PersistenceContext.synchronization()Ljavax/persistence/SynchronizationType; but it does not exist. Its class, javax.persistence.PersistenceContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/thiag/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/thiag/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/thiag/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.persistence.PersistenceContext


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Estou usando o MySql e JPA para realizar o processo de persistência. A versão do meu JDK é 8!

Segue meu arquivo POM.xml contendo as dependências do projeto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.aimbra</groupId>
    <artifactId>ponto-eletronico</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ponto-eletronico</name>
    <description>Software de ponto eletronico</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Classe importante para o projeto-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Fim classe importante para o projeto-->

        <!--Banco de dados-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--spring Security-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Hibernate Validator-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Desde já, agradeço a colaboração!

Comment: roda o comando mvn dependency:tree, ele vai te mostrar tudo que foi importado e de qual dependencia, provavelmente você está importando dependencias que possuem essas duas versões distintas, o que causa o conflito, eu chutaria que é o entitymanager

Comment: Consegui resolver esse negócio! Devo postar em breve na resposta! 10h para resolver um problema.

Comment: Acho que você poderia remover as dependências de hibernate e JPA e deixar apenas do starter do Spring Data